# Comparison prompts syntax error

Tags: scala

For the following code, `x<y` portion prompts syntax error, may I know should I modify it to enable the comparison?

```
class SortAlgo {
def insert[T](x:T, xs:List[T]): List[T]= xs match{
  case Nil=> List(x)
  case y::ys=>
    if(x<y) x::xs
    else y::insert(x,ys)
}

def isort[T:Comparable](xs:List[T]): List[T]=xs match{

   case Nil => Nil
   case x :: xs1 => insert(x, isort(xs1))
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `Ordering`, instead of `Comparable`, you can `import` the necessary implicits to enable `<` comparisons.

```
import Ordering.Implicits._
class SortAlgo[T: Ordering] {
  def insert(x:T, xs:List[T]): List[T]= xs match {
    case Nil=> List(x)
    case y::ys=>
      if(x<y) x::xs
      else y::insert(x,ys)
  }

  def isort(xs:List[T]): List[T]=xs match {
    case Nil => Nil
    case x :: xs1 => insert(x, isort(xs1))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`x` and `y` are of type `T` but nothing indicates that `T` has `<` method.

Two options:

1 - Require that `T` extends `Ordered[T]`:

```
def insert[T <: Ordered[T]](x:T, xs:List[T]): List[T] = ...
```

2 - Provided an `Ordering`:

```
def insert[T](x: T, xs: List[T])(ordering: Ordering[T]): List[T] = {
  case Nil => List(x)
  case y::ys =>
    if (ordering.compare(x, y) < 0) => x::xs
    else y::insert(x, ys)
}
```

You might want to the `ordering` implicit so you can create implicit object extending `Ordering[T]`.